# How to perform update operation on MS Dynamics CRM (OnDemand) for boolean fields in entity

Tags: mule, mule-studio

Using the update operation of Mule MS Dynamics CRM connector, 
I am able to do 'update' operation on 'contact' entity for fields like "fullname", "name" etc.., whose datatype is String, but unable to update in case of Boolean datatypes.

Exception log at console: "System.InvalidCastException: Microsoft Dynamics CRM has experienced an error. Reference number for administrators or support: #BF667EAF"

Could you please let me know how to perform update operation in case of Boolean or Integer datatypes.

Comment: Can you show your config?

Comment: @DavidDossot : I have solved the problem. <br/>
below is configuration-xml snippet <br/>
** 
<dynamicscrm:update config-ref="CRM_Instance" guid="348E648A-F4E6-E111-B218-78E3B511B6CD" logicalName="account" doc:name="MS Dynamics CRM">
 <dynamicscrm:attributes-to-update>
  <dynamicscrm:attributes-to-update key="new_bool_field">new Boolean(true);</dynamicscrm:attributes-to-update>
 </dynamicscrm:attributes-to-update>
</dynamicscrm:update>
** <br/> 
anyways thanks David.

Comment: Answer your question then accept the answer, for the sake of the rest of the community. Thanks.